# Get the results of a flow into a global variable

Tags: talend

I have a flow in my Talend job that returns just one value (one row with one column), and I want to store this value in a global variable. What is the best way to do it? So far I have been using tFlowToIterate in this scenario, but this seems like a hack - because I really do not need to iterate. I'm wondering if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Can you add some more info about your data flow according anyone can suggest how to do this. Otherwise it is a very broad question because in different scenario there are different way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is different solutions personnaly I also use the tFlowToIterate method but you can also use the tJava components or juste use the tSetGlobalVar component which is the component use in this case (one row).

Here is how to use it :

[image]

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason tJava always gets null. But, if I use tJavaRow - it works!